# Using relay instead of L293d

Tags: relay, l293d

I want to control a dc motor that I have . I don't need any speed or direction control just plain on/off. I was wondering if using a 5v dc relay is better or worse. My only requirement is to have as much low power consumption as possible.

Comment: If you need neither speed nor direction control, then you can get rid of the H bridge, and use just one switch (transistor, relay, whatever), provided it is good for the voltage, current, and transients from the motor, and has an input that works for whatever you are controlling it from

Answer (score 1):

Energy requirement would be minimum with a magnetic latch relay.

[image]

Only a single pulse would be required for 'On' / 'Off'.

The 'NO' contact, of the latch relay K1, would drive the motor.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the datasheet for the relay you want to use. Make sure the specs of your motor are within the specs of your relay. Mainly voltage and current for the "in rush" of turning it on or "stall" condition of the motor. If the motor is a small dc hobby motor than the answer for most relays is probably yes but always look at the datasheet.

Also don't forget a flyback diode for both the motor and for the relay coil.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you an exact answer as you never gave us the parameters of the motor or the control signal. If it were me I would use an open drain UIS rated MOSFET device. The rating depends on the motor, more amps within reason on the MOSFET is good. You can connect the 5V signal directly to the gate but a 50 Ohm resistor in series would be nice. The exact parameters are in the MOSFET data sheet. The output would go to the low side (-) of your motor and the (+) side of the motor would go to the positive voltage. Then with 0V on the Gate the leakage will be in the microamp range. With 5V on the gate the MOSFET will not consume energy as it is a voltage driven device not a current device as a relay would be. The picture shows the connection, what is not shown is the 12V ground to the 0V. You can get DC switches that are opto coupled MOSFETs for a few dollars from your favorite china supplier. AC switches will not work, they need a zero cross to turn off, the MOSFET does not. If you use an AC switch it will turn on but not off.

[image]